# Weird encoding issues with html contact form and utf8 encoding through meta tag

Tags: html, forms, unicode, utf-8

I have this simple contact form:

```
<form id="emailForm" action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="email">Your email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

    <p class="emailPop" id="emailError"></p>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

If a message contains unicode characters like `àèìòù` they will display in a weird way when I receive the email containing the message that I've been sent, like for example `Ã Ã Ã Ã¹Ã²Ã¨Ã²Ã²Ã²Ã¨Ã Ã¨Ã Ã Ã²`.

I excerpted the form to a page which only contained the form alone and messages from that page reached my email with no modifications. After a bit of experimenting I discovered that the cause of the issue is the tag `<meta charset="utf-8">`, the one that's actually supposed to make things work.

Since other pages make use of unicode characters I can not go without this tag, but it will conflict with the output of my form. What should I do?

---

Here's the code of the php script in charge of sending the email

```
<?php
    //require_once 'Mail.php';

    function exit_message($error) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $error));
        exit();
    }

    $data = $_POST;

    // Check that all fields are filled in
    $fields = array('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message');

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if(empty($data[$field]))
            exit_message("Please insert your " . $field . '.');
    }

    // Check if email is valid
    if(!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        exit_message('The email you provided is invalid.');

    // Check if message is longer than 9 characters
    if(strlen($data['message']) <= 9)
        exit_message('Please write a message at least 9 characters long.');

    // Begin composing the message
    $message = array(
        'recipient' => 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'subject' => $data['subject'],
        'body' => stripslashes($data['message']) . ' - gabrielecirulli.com',
        'headers' => 'From: "' . $data['name'] . '" <' . $data['email'] . '>'
    );

    // Send
    if(mail(
        $message['recipient'],
        utf8_encode($message['subject']),
        utf8_encode($message['body']),
        $message['headers']
    )) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
    } else {
        exit_message('An unidentified error happened while sending your message.');
    }
```

---

Here's an example: if i send the message through my page
http://www.gabrielecirulli.com/p/20120113-073417.png

and if I send the same message through the test page which doesn't have `<meta charset="utf-8">`:
http://www.gabrielecirulli.com/p/20120113-073503.png

Here's the result:
http://www.gabrielecirulli.com/p/20120113-073737.png

As you can see the page without the meta tag actually gives the right characters.

This issue appears in both Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This is all about your email sending mechanism, not about your form.

Comment: No, it is not. Sending the message from the page without the meta tag results in a sane email. When the meta tag is added, those symbols appear.

Comment: You always need to specify what encoding something is in. You need to set meta information that tell the browser which encoding to interpret text in and in which encoding it should send text to the server. The same goes for emails, you need to set headers that tell an email client what encoding the mail is in. So it *is* all about how exactly you send email!

Comment: I've updated the question with an example, please check it out.

Comment: Yes, we *get* the problem. Please show us the code that sends the email.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `utf8_encode` for the body and subject! Your data is already in UTF-8 when it comes from the browser, you do not need to *convert* it from Latin-1 to UTF-8 (which is what `utf8_encode` does).

You should also add proper headers to the message that designate its encoding:

```
'headers' => 'From: "' . $data['name'] . '" <' . $data['email'] . ">\r\n" .
             "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
             'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

There's also no need for `stripslashes` on the body, *unless* you have Magic Quotes on, in which case you should rather deactivate Magic Quotes.